# JAX-WS & JSR 330 (Spring) - cannot inject dependency

Tags: dependency-injection, jax-ws, java-ee-6

I cannot seem to inject a simple bean into my `@WebService`. With Spring on the classpath and `javax.inject` dependencies defined, I created a simple JAX-WS webservice with some underlying interface-driven DAOs etc:

```
@Named
@WebService(name = "NoteStorage", serviceName = "NoteStorageWS")
public class NoteStorageWS implements NoteStore {

    private static final Log l = LogFactory.getLog(NoteStorageWS.class);

    @Named("NoteDAO")
    @Inject
    private NoteDAO noteDAO;

    public NoteStorageWS() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public StorageState takeNote(String note) {
        try {
            l.info(format("Service received message: '%s'", note));

            Note n = new Note();
            n.setContent(note);
            noteDAO.store(n);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            l.error(e);
            return StorageState.FAILURE;
        }
        return StorageState.SUCCESS;
    }

    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public void setNoteDAO(NoteDAO noteDAO) {
        this.noteDAO = noteDAO;
    }
}
```

`NoteDAO`has just implementation: `FlatFileNoteDAO` which is defined as follows:

```
@Named("NoteDAO")
public class FlatFileNoteDAO implements NoteDAO {

    private static final Log l = LogFactory.getLog(FlatFileNoteDAO.class);

    @Override
    public void store(Note n) {
        if (n == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Note was null");
        }

        try {
            l.info(format("Storing note '%s'", n));
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("Note"));
            fileWriter.write(format("%s\n", n.getContent()));
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DataAccessException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

My web.xml says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

I deploy the application to Glassfish by pointing it to the target/note-ws/ directory and execute the simple `takeNote` method via the `?Tester` page.

Upon submission of the tester form I get a `NullPointerException` at the line `noteDAO.store(n);`, presumably because noteDAO wasn't injected.

I can confirm that Spring has been invoked by the logs from glassfish on context initialisation (the Java EE context):

```
[#|2011-12-04T16:57:24.970+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner|_ThreadID=256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning|#]

    [#|2011-12-04T16:57:25.653+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor|_ThreadID=256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring|#]

    [#|2011-12-04T16:57:25.757+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|_ThreadID=256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9e39146: defining beans [noteStorageWS,NoteDAO,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy|#]
```

which says my beans are defined: `noteStorageWS`, `NoteDAO` and so-on.

Any ideas?

**Edit**
 to clarify, I'm using Spring to provide JSR 330 -- dependency injection -- functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got this solved, so I ended up removing the DI-features as the codebase was small and relied on manual dependency resolution - plain old `new IFaceImpl();` for now.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-WS and Guice require a specific integration via `@GuiceManaged` annotation. More info [here](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/guice/).

Comment: I'm not using Guice -- are you saying I should be or that it's required in addition?

Comment: Which JSR-330 implementation are you using?

Comment: Spring, as stated in the original post: "Spring on the classpath"

Comment: I have just learned that Spring implements JSR-330 :) I am under the impression that two different instances of NoteStorageWS get created. One by Spring, which actually has the injected DAO, and the other one by the Glassfish container as a result of the WebService annotation (which is the one used when calling the WS), but this is just a thought. Can you try to place an empty beans.xml file in the META-INF directory of the jar in which the service is placed? This will tell glassfish that there are managed beans in your package, although they won't be managed by Spring.

Comment: An empty beans.xml is already there. I tried to simplify it all by removing the Spring imports, but no luck :|

Answer (score 0):

Move the business logic to a separate bean and annotate it with @Configurable so that Spring can handle the lifecycle of the bean. Now use that bean in NoteStorageWS

```
    @Configurable
    public class NoteStorageUtil{
       @Named("NoteDAO")
       @Inject
       private NoteDAO noteDAO;

       public StorageState takeNote(String note) {
         try {
                l.info(format("Service received message: '%s'", note));
                Note n = new Note();
                n.setContent(note);
                noteDAO.store(n);

          } catch (Exception e) {
                l.error(e);
                return StorageState.FAILURE;
          }
          return StorageState.SUCCESS;
       }
    }

    @WebService(name = "NoteStorage", serviceName = "NoteStorageWS")
    public class NoteStorageWS implements NoteStore {
        public StorageState takeNote(String note) {
            return new NoteStorageUtil().takeNote(note)
        }
    }
```

Or please check if your end point configuration is proper, so that the web service end point is a spring-managed bean also. 
Eg:-

```
   <bean id="hello" class="demo.spring.service.HelloWorldImpl" />
   <jaxws:endpoint id="helloWorld" implementor="#hello" address="/HelloWorld" />
```

check [the link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html#WritingaservicewithSpring-Declaringyourserverbeans)